# Create a stacked bar chart with plotly provide only one color instead of two

Tags: r, plotly

I have the dataframe below:

```
dp<-structure(list(`Demand Per Section` = c(125, 350, 100, 538, 75, 
25, 138, 138, 75, 150, 37, 225, 35, 40, 125, 25, 25, 125, 50, 
250, 88, 325, 4, 50, 6, 5, 500, 500, 3, 146, 5, 34, 15, 51, 2, 
32, 48, 18, 5, 6, 44, 16, 46, 12, 100, 750, 15, 500, 30, 333), 
    `Element Name` = c("Nitric acid (concentrated)", "Sulphuric acid(concentrated)", 
    "2-hydroxybenzoic acid", "Acetic anhydride", "2-Naphthol", 
    "Sodium Hydroxide", "Phenyl hydrazine hydrochloride", "Glucose", 
    "Sodium acetate", "Aniline", "Zinc poweder", "2-amino-benzoic acid", 
    "1.3-dihydroxybenzene", "Ethyl acetate", "hydroxy benzene", 
    "phenyl methanol", "Sodium carbonate", "Potassium permanganate", 
    "Sodium bisulfite.", "Hydrochloric acid (concentrated)", 
    "Sodium nitrite", "Copper(II) sulfate", "Methyl orange", 
    "EtOH", "Distilled water", "cuper ion", "ammonium hydroxide", 
    "ammonium hydroxide", "Iron( III)", "Potassium Thiocyanate", 
    "ferric ammonium sulfate", "Ammonium Sulfate", "sodium hypochlorite", 
    "Acetic acid", "Phenolphthalein", "Sodium carbonate", "Sodum hydroxide", 
    "Acetic acid", "Phenolphthalein", "Methyl orange", "Phosphoric acid", 
    "Sodium carbonate", "Iron(II) sulfate", "Potassium permanganate", 
    "Sulfuric Acid", "Barium Chloride.monoHydrate", "Distilled water", 
    "nickel Sulphate", "Dimethyl glyoxime (DMG)", "Calsium chloride"
    ), Department = c("Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry","Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry"), DemandCourse = c(375, 1050, 300, 
    1614, 225, 75, 414, 414, 225, 450, 111, 675, 105, 120, 375, 
    75, 75, 375, 150, 750, 264, 975, 20, 250, 30, 25, 2500, 2500, 
    15, 730, 25, 170, 75, 255, 10, 160, 144, 54, 15, 18, 132, 
    48, 138, 36, 300, 2250, 45, 1500, 90, 999), `Amount Available` = c(1000, 
    3000, 4000, 1000, 750, 750, 2000, 5000, 150, 24000, 450, 
    3000, 1400, 400, 400, 250, 250, 1000, 1000, 7500, 6400, 900, 
    250, 1500, 20000, 50, 300, 4000, 200, 3000, 500, 1200, 1000, 
    6000, 900, 250, 200, 6000, 900, 250, 200, 250, 150, 1000, 
    15000, 3000, 20000, 1500, 600, 7500)), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(c(`1` = 1L, 
`24` = 24L, `32` = 32L, `36` = 36L, `38` = 38L, `42` = 42L, `45` = 45L, 
`49` = 49L, `66` = 66L, `111` = 111L, `140` = 140L, `151` = 151L, 
`154` = 154L, `164` = 164L, `169` = 169L, `171` = 171L, `175` = 175L,`185` = 185L, `193` = 193L, `227` = 227L, `252` = 252L, `253` = 253L, 
`256` = 256L, `257` = 257L, `258` = 258L, `262` = 262L, `263` = 263L, 
`265` = 265L, `275` = 275L, `276` = 276L, `277` = 277L, `279` = 279L, 
`280` = 280L, `281` = 281L, `282` = 282L, `283` = 283L, `284` = 284L, 
`285` = 285L, `286` = 286L, `288` = 288L, `289` = 289L, `290` = 290L, 
`291` = 291L, `292` = 292L, `293` = 293L, `298` = 298L, `299` = 299L, 
`300` = 300L, `302` = 302L, `303` = 303L, `304` = 304L, `308` = 308L, 
`309` = 309L, `310` = 310L, `311` = 311L, `312` = 312L, `314` = 314L, 
`315` = 315L, `316` = 316L, `317` = 317L, `318` = 318L, `319` = 319L, 
`323` = 323L, `325` = 325L), class = "omit"))
```

and I want to create stacked bar chart with `Amount Available` and `DemandCourse` but its not working.

```
fig <- plot_ly(
  data = as.data.frame(dp),
  x = ~ `Element Name`,
  y = ~ `Amount Available`,
  name = "Amount Available",
  hovertext = paste(
    "Chemical Name:",dp$`Element Name`,
    "<br>Available Amount :",
    dp$`Amount Available`
    
  ),
  hoverinfo = "text"
)%>% add_trace(y = ~DemandCourse, name = 'Demand',
               hovertext = paste(
                 "Chemical Name:",dp$`Element Name`,
                 "<br>Available Amount :",
                 dp$`DemandCourse`
                 
               ),
               hoverinfo = "text")%>% layout(showlegend=T,
                                             barmode="stack"
                                             
                                             #legend = list(title = list(text = "<b>Department</b>"))
               )

fig
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plotly` doesn't understand when back ticks are surrounding the variable name that it's still a column in the data. (With regard to the hovertext, specifically.) There are a few ways to get around this. Since you're still using the x and y of each trace, you can use `hovertemplate` instead.

---

updated

---

After I posted this answer I noticed that 2500 looked the same size as 4000 and that's not quite right. From there I recalled that `plotly` won't aggregate the totals. You can aggregate before or during, but it won't automatically sum the values.

Also, the function `aggregate` won't accept variable names in back ticks, either.

I've updated the code here to aggregate the totals so that your `hovertext` shows the total by group, not individual layers as you move your mouse down the column.

I added x and y labels in the call to `layout`, because the backticks were in the graph.

```
dp <- as.data.frame(dp)

fig <- plot_ly(data = aggregate(list(y = dp[, 5]),
                                list(x = dp[, 2]),
                                sum), 
               x = ~x,
               y = ~y, name = "Amount Available",
               hovertemplate = "Chemical Name: %{x}<br>Available Amount: %{y}",
               type = "bar") %>% 
  add_bars(data = aggregate(list(y = dp[, 4]),
                            list(x = dp[, 2]),
                            sum),
           x = ~x,
           y = ~y, name = "Demand",
           hovertemplate = "Chemical Name: %{x}<br>Available Amount: %{y}",
           inherit = F) %>% 
  layout(barmode = "stack",
         xaxis = list(title = "Element Names"),
         yaxis = list(title = "Amount Available",
                      range = c(0, 45000)))
fig
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: great thank you in the hovwertemplate how can I add also another variable lets say Department

Comment: How do you want to add *Department*? Did you want each of these traces grouped by Department? Or are you asking in what possible ways could you add this variable?    BTW... I've updated my answer with notes as to why I did that.

Comment: I mean to have it in the hovertext

Comment: That depends on a few things. Right now the data is grouped by the chemicals, if there is more than one department within that stack, then you would either have to group by Department *and* the chemical, group the data by neither, or list all departments within a column by color. I realize it's all one department in this data, but I didn't think you wanted a data-specific answer (perhaps a dynamic answer that can be reapplied to other data or larger versions of this data).

Comment: yes the number of departments may vary in any case I opened a new Q for this since you answered the original Q here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71428124/edit-the-hovertemplate-by-adding-another-variable-except-ofthose-used-as-x-and-y

Comment: how can I skip this trace text which is displayd out of the hover box?

Comment: At the end of both of the quoted strings following the argument `hovertemplate` (still within the quotes), add `<extra></extra>`.  That will remove the trace name from the hover text. For example: `hovertemplate = "Chemical Name: %{x}<br>Available Amount: %{y}<extra></extra>"`

Comment: thanks that worked any idea for this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71441124/remove-text-which-is-didplayed-on-bars-in-plotly-bar-chart