# Edit the hovertemplate by adding another variable except of those used as x and y

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I have the dataframe below:

```
dp <- structure(list(`Demand Per Section` = c(125, 350, 100, 538, 75, 
25, 138, 138, 75, 150, 37, 225, 35, 40, 125, 25, 25, 125, 50, 
250, 88, 325, 4, 50, 6, 5, 500, 500, 3, 146, 5, 34, 15, 51, 2, 
32, 48, 18, 5, 6, 44, 16, 46, 12, 100, 750, 15, 500, 30, 333), 
    `Element Name` = c("Nitric acid (concentrated)", "Sulphuric acid(concentrated)", 
    "2-hydroxybenzoic acid", "Acetic anhydride", "2-Naphthol", 
    "Sodium Hydroxide", "Phenyl hydrazine hydrochloride", "Glucose", 
    "Sodium acetate", "Aniline", "Zinc poweder", "2-amino-benzoic acid", 
    "1.3-dihydroxybenzene", "Ethyl acetate", "hydroxy benzene", 
    "phenyl methanol", "Sodium carbonate", "Potassium permanganate", 
    "Sodium bisulfite.", "Hydrochloric acid (concentrated)", 
    "Sodium nitrite", "Copper(II) sulfate", "Methyl orange", 
    "EtOH", "Distilled water", "cuper ion", "ammonium hydroxide", 
    "ammonium hydroxide", "Iron( III)", "Potassium Thiocyanate", 
    "ferric ammonium sulfate", "Ammonium Sulfate", "sodium hypochlorite", 
    "Acetic acid", "Phenolphthalein", "Sodium carbonate", "Sodum hydroxide", 
    "Acetic acid", "Phenolphthalein", "Methyl orange", "Phosphoric acid", 
    "Sodium carbonate", "Iron(II) sulfate", "Potassium permanganate", 
    "Sulfuric Acid", "Barium Chloride.monoHydrate", "Distilled water", 
    "nickel Sulphate", "Dimethyl glyoxime (DMG)", "Calsium chloride"
    ), Department = c("Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Physics", "Physics", "Physics", "Physics", 
    "Physics", "Physics", "Physics", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry","Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
    "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry"), DemandCourse = c(375, 1050, 300, 
    1614, 225, 75, 414, 414, 225, 450, 111, 675, 105, 120, 375, 
    75, 75, 375, 150, 750, 264, 975, 20, 250, 30, 25, 2500, 2500, 
    15, 730, 25, 170, 75, 255, 10, 160, 144, 54, 15, 18, 132, 
    48, 138, 36, 300, 2250, 45, 1500, 90, 999), `Amount Available` = c(1000, 
    3000, 4000, 1000, 750, 750, 2000, 5000, 150, 24000, 450, 
    3000, 1400, 400, 400, 250, 250, 1000, 1000, 7500, 6400, 900, 
    250, 1500, 20000, 50, 300, 4000, 200, 3000, 500, 1200, 1000, 
    6000, 900, 250, 200, 6000, 900, 250, 200, 250, 150, 1000, 
    15000, 3000, 20000, 1500, 600, 7500)), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(c(`1` = 1L, 
`24` = 24L, `32` = 32L, `36` = 36L, `38` = 38L, `42` = 42L, `45` = 45L, 
`49` = 49L, `66` = 66L, `111` = 111L, `140` = 140L, `151` = 151L, 
`154` = 154L, `164` = 164L, `169` = 169L, `171` = 171L, `175` = 175L,`185` = 185L, `193` = 193L, `227` = 227L, `252` = 252L, `253` = 253L, 
`256` = 256L, `257` = 257L, `258` = 258L, `262` = 262L, `263` = 263L, 
`265` = 265L, `275` = 275L, `276` = 276L, `277` = 277L, `279` = 279L, 
`280` = 280L, `281` = 281L, `282` = 282L, `283` = 283L, `284` = 284L, 
`285` = 285L, `286` = 286L, `288` = 288L, `289` = 289L, `290` = 290L, 
`291` = 291L, `292` = 292L, `293` = 293L, `298` = 298L, `299` = 299L, 
`300` = 300L, `302` = 302L, `303` = 303L, `304` = 304L, `308` = 308L, 
`309` = 309L, `310` = 310L, `311` = 311L, `312` = 312L, `314` = 314L, 
`315` = 315L, `316` = 316L, `317` = 317L, `318` = 318L, `319` = 319L, 
`323` = 323L, `325` = 325L), class = "omit"))
```

and I create a stacked bar chart based on `DemandCourse` and `Amount Available`. I would like in the hovertemplate though to display the `Department` as well. Even if the bars are separated by slices for each `Department`. Or find alternative way.

```
fig <- plot_ly(x = ~`Element Name`, data = dp) %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~`DemandCourse`, name = "Demand",
           hovertemplate = "Chemical Name: %{x}<br>Demand: %{y}") %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~`Amount Available`, name = "Amount Available",
           hovertemplate = "Chemical Name: %{x}<br>Available Amount: %{y}") %>% 
  
  layout(showLegend = T, barmode = "stack",
         xaxis = list(title = "Element Name",tickangle=45),
         yaxis = list(title = "Amount Available"),
         title="Amount and Demand per Element")
fig
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `hovertext` parameter to show additional infos:

```
fig <- plot_ly(x = ~ `Element Name`, data = dp) %>%
  add_bars(
    y = ~ `DemandCourse`,
    name = "Demand",
    hovertext = ~ paste("Department:", Department),
    hovertemplate = "Chemical Name: %{x}<br>Demand: %{y}<br>%{hovertext}<extra></extra>"
  ) %>%
  add_bars(
    y = ~ `Amount Available`,
    name = "Amount Available",
    hovertext = ~ paste("Department:", Department),
    hovertemplate = "Chemical Name: %{x}<br>Available Amount: %{y}<br>%{hovertext}<extra></extra>"
  ) %>%
  layout(
    showlegend = TRUE,
    barmode = "stack",
    xaxis = list(title = "Element Name", tickangle = 45),
    yaxis = list(title = "Amount Available"),
    title = "Amount and Demand per Element"
  )
fig
```

Also see this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71478656/9841389).