# Edit the plotly hovertemplate by adding a new row

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I have the `data.frame` below and I have created a grouped bar chart. I'd like to edit the hover text by adding a new row after `Department` which will be named `Department value` and will take the column `DemandCourse.x` as its value for group `Demand` and `AmountsAv.x` for the group `Amount Available`.

```
dp <- structure(list(`Element Name` = c("Naphthalene", "Nitric acid (concentrated)", 
"Sulphuric acid(concentrated)", "2-hydroxybenzoic acid", "Acetic anhydride", 
"2-Naphthol", "Sodium Hydroxide", "Phenyl hydrazine hydrochloride", 
"Glucose", "Sodium acetate", "Aniline", "Zinc poweder", "2-amino-benzoic acid", 
"1.3-dihydroxybenzene", "Ethyl acetate", "hydroxy benzene", "phenyl methanol", 
"Sodium carbonate", "Potassium permanganate", "Sodium bisulfite.", 
"Hydrochloric acid (concentrated)", "Sodium nitrite", "Copper(II) sulfate", 
"Sodium chloride.", "Methyl orange", "EtOH", "Distilled water", 
"cuper ion", "ammonium hydroxide", "ammonium hydroxide", "Iron( III)", 
"Nitric Acid", "Potassium Thiocyanate", "ferric ammonium sulfate", 
"Ammonium Sulfate", "Sodium hydroxide", "sodium hypochlorite", 
"Hydrochloric acid", "Acetic acid", "Phenolphthalein", "Sodium carbonate", 
"Sodium Acetate", "Sodum hydroxide", "Acetic acid", "Hydrochloric acid", 
"Phenolphthalein", "Methyl orange", "Phosphoric acid", "Amonium hydroxide", 
"Sodium carbonate"), Department = c("Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
"Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
"Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
"Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
"Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
"Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
"Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
"Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
"Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry","Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", 
"Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry"), DemandCourse.x = c(240, 
375, 1050, 300, 1614, 225, 75, 414, 414, 225, 450, 111, 675, 
105, 120, 375, 75, 75, 375, 150, 750, 264, 975, 900, 20, 250, 
30, 25, 2500, 2500, 15, 500, 730, 25, 170, 240, 75, 750, 255, 
10, 160, 50, 144, 54, 630, 15, 18, 132, 900, 48), DemandCourse.y = c(1115, 
375, 1050, 300, 1739, 225, 800, 414, 414, 225, 450, 111, 675, 
105, 224.5, 375, 75, 613, 601, 150, 1070, 364, 1519, 1095, 96.75, 
250, 293, 25, 29500, 29500, 15, 500, 730, 25, 170, 240, 75, 1420, 
534, 63, 613, 50, 144, 534, 1420, 63, 96.75, 152, 900, 613), 
    AmountsAv.x = c(NA, 1000, 3000, 4000, 1000, 750, 750, 2000, 
    5000, 150, 24000, 450, 3000, 1400, 400, 400, 250, 250, 1000, 
    1000, 7500, 6400, 900, NA, 250, 1500, 20000, 50, 300, 4000, 
    200, NA, 3000, 500, 1200, NA, 1000, NA, 6000, 900, 250, NA, 
    200, 6000, NA, 900, 250, 200, NA, 250), AmountsAv.y = c(0, 
    1000, 3000, 4000, 2000, 750, 4500, 2000, 5000, 150, 24000, 
    450, 3000, 1400, 1200, 400, 250, 1500, 5000, 1000, 22500, 
    12800, 2700, 0, 1500, 1500, 80000, 50, 8600, 8600, 200, 0, 
    3000, 500, 1200, 0, 1000, 0, 30000, 4500, 1500, 0, 200, 30000, 
    0, 4500, 1500, 400, 0, 1500)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(293:294, .Names = c("293", 
"294"), class = "omit"))



fig <- plot_ly(x = ~`Element Name`,text=~Department, data = merged3) %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~`DemandCourse.y`, 
           name = "Demand", 
           textposition = "none",          # <--- added here
           hovertemplate = paste0("Chemical Name: %{x}<br>", 
                                  "Total Demand: %{y}<br>",
                                  "Department: %{text}<br><extra></extra>")) %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~`AmountsAv.y`,
           name = "Amount Available", 
           textposition = "none",          # <--- added here
           hovertemplate = paste0("Chemical Name: %{x}<br>",  
                                  "Total Amount: %{y}<br>",
                                  "Department: %{text}<br><extra></extra>")) %>% 
  layout(barmode = "group",             # <--- dropped showLegend (doesn't go here)
         xaxis = list(title = "Element Name", tickangle=45),
         yaxis = list(title = "Amount Available"),
         title = "Amount and Demand per Element")
fig
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Using `hovertext` instead of `text` and `textposition = "none"` (also see this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71479068/9841389))

```
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly(x = ~`Element Name`, data = dp) %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~`DemandCourse.y`, 
           name = "Demand", 
           hovertext = ~ paste0("Chemical Name: ", `Element Name`, "<br>", 
                          "Total Demand: ", `DemandCourse.y`, "<br>",
                          "Department: " , Department, "<br>",
                          "Department value: " , DemandCourse.x),
           hovertemplate = "%{hovertext}<extra></extra>") %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~`AmountsAv.y`,
           name = "Amount Available", 
           hovertext = ~ paste0("Chemical Name: ", `Element Name`, "<br>", 
                          "Total Amount: ", `AmountsAv.y`, "<br>",
                          "Department: " , Department, "<br>",
                          "Department value: " , AmountsAv.x),
           hovertemplate = "%{hovertext}<extra></extra>") %>% 
  layout(barmode = "group",
         xaxis = list(title = "Element Name", tickangle=45),
         yaxis = list(title = "Amount Available"),
         title = "Amount and Demand per Element")
fig
```

---

You can construct most of the `hovertemplate` in the `text` parameter to solve this:

```
dp <- structure(list(`Element Name` = c("Naphthalene", "Nitric acid
(concentrated)", "Sulphuric acid(concentrated)", "2-hydroxybenzoic acid",
"Acetic anhydride", "2-Naphthol", "Sodium Hydroxide", "Phenyl hydrazine
hydrochloride", "Glucose", "Sodium acetate", "Aniline", "Zinc poweder",
"2-amino-benzoic acid", "1.3-dihydroxybenzene", "Ethyl acetate", "hydroxy
benzene", "phenyl methanol", "Sodium carbonate", "Potassium permanganate",
"Sodium bisulfite.", "Hydrochloric acid (concentrated)", "Sodium nitrite",
"Copper(II) sulfate", "Sodium chloride.", "Methyl orange", "EtOH", "Distilled
water", "cuper ion", "ammonium hydroxide", "ammonium hydroxide", "Iron( III)",
"Nitric Acid", "Potassium Thiocyanate", "ferric ammonium sulfate", "Ammonium
Sulfate", "Sodium hydroxide", "sodium hypochlorite", "Hydrochloric acid",
"Acetic acid", "Phenolphthalein", "Sodium carbonate", "Sodium Acetate", "Sodum
hydroxide", "Acetic acid", "Hydrochloric acid", "Phenolphthalein", "Methyl
orange", "Phosphoric acid", "Amonium hydroxide", "Sodium carbonate"),
Department = c("Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry",
"Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry",
"Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry",
"Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry",
"Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry",
"Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry",
"Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry",
"Chemsitry", "Chemsitry","Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry",
"Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry", "Chemsitry"), DemandCourse.x = c(240,
375, 1050, 300, 1614, 225, 75, 414, 414, 225, 450, 111, 675, 105, 120, 375,
75, 75, 375, 150, 750, 264, 975, 900, 20, 250, 30, 25, 2500, 2500, 15, 500,
730, 25, 170, 240, 75, 750, 255, 10, 160, 50, 144, 54, 630, 15, 18, 132, 900,
48), DemandCourse.y = c(1115, 375, 1050, 300, 1739, 225, 800, 414, 414, 225,
450, 111, 675, 105, 224.5, 375, 75, 613, 601, 150, 1070, 364, 1519, 1095,
96.75, 250, 293, 25, 29500, 29500, 15, 500, 730, 25, 170, 240, 75, 1420, 534,
63, 613, 50, 144, 534, 1420, 63, 96.75, 152, 900, 613), AmountsAv.x = c(NA,
1000, 3000, 4000, 1000, 750, 750, 2000, 5000, 150, 24000, 450, 3000, 1400,
400, 400, 250, 250, 1000, 1000, 7500, 6400, 900, NA, 250, 1500, 20000, 50,
300, 4000, 200, NA, 3000, 500, 1200, NA, 1000, NA, 6000, 900, 250, NA, 200,
6000, NA, 900, 250, 200, NA, 250), AmountsAv.y = c(0, 1000, 3000, 4000, 2000,
750, 4500, 2000, 5000, 150, 24000, 450, 3000, 1400, 1200, 400, 250, 1500,
5000, 1000, 22500, 12800, 2700, 0, 1500, 1500, 80000, 50, 8600, 8600, 200, 0,
3000, 500, 1200, 0, 1000, 0, 30000, 4500, 1500, 0, 200, 30000, 0, 4500, 1500,
400, 0, 1500)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl",
"data.frame"), na.action = structure(293:294, .Names = c("293", "294"), class
= "omit"))



library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly(x = ~`Element Name`, data = dp) %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~`DemandCourse.y`, 
           name = "Demand", 
           textposition = "none",
           text= ~ paste0("Chemical Name: ", `Element Name`, "<br>", 
                          "Total Demand: ", `DemandCourse.y`, "<br>",
                          "Department: " , Department, "<br>",
                          "Department value: " , DemandCourse.x),
           hovertemplate = "%{text}<extra></extra>") %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~`AmountsAv.y`,
           name = "Amount Available", 
           textposition = "none",
           text= ~ paste0("Chemical Name: ", `Element Name`, "<br>", 
                          "Total Amount: ", `AmountsAv.y`, "<br>",
                          "Department: " , Department, "<br>",
                          "Department value: " , AmountsAv.x),
           hovertemplate = "%{text}<extra></extra>") %>% 
  layout(barmode = "group",
         xaxis = list(title = "Element Name", tickangle=45),
         yaxis = list(title = "Amount Available"),
         title = "Amount and Demand per Element")
fig
```