# Using custom text in R Plotly tooltip fails to show %{text} values

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to use `text =`  and `%{text}` to display `myvar1` values in Plotly bars, and also as part of the tooltip text. However, my code fails to produce the tooltip adequatly and shows "%{text}" instead of its corresponding value (as shown in image below).

[image: Wrong tooltip]

Here is my code:

```
library(plotly)
dfcom <- data.frame(
  myvar1 = c("Media", "Campaigns", "Website"),
  alcance = c(6814511L, 400000L, 225329L),
  type = c("viewers", "viewers", "viewers"))
plot_ly(
  dfcom,
  x = ~alcance, y = ~type,
  text = ~myvar1,
  textfont = list(color = I("white")),
  type = 'bar',
  color = ~myvar1,
  colors = c("chartreuse4", "darkolivegreen", "darkgreen"),
  showlegend = FALSE,
  hovertemplate = "%{x:,.0f} people reached by %{text} <extra></extra>") %>%
  layout(barmode = "stack")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why `%{text}` or `%{hovertext}` fail ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71478968/9841389) it's working), however, `%{customdata}` seems to work:

```
library(plotly)
dfcom <- data.frame(
  myvar1 = c("Media", "Campaigns", "Website"),
  alcance = c(6814511L, 400000L, 225329L),
  type = c("viewers", "viewers", "viewers")
)
plot_ly(
  data = dfcom,
  x = ~ alcance,
  y = ~ type,
  text = ~ myvar1,
  # hovertext = ~ myvar1,
  customdata = ~ myvar1,
  textfont = list(color = I("white")),
  type = 'bar',
  color = ~ myvar1,
  colors = c("chartreuse4", "darkolivegreen", "darkgreen"),
  showlegend = FALSE,
  hovertemplate = "%{x:,.0f} people reached by %{customdata}<extra></extra>"
) %>%
  layout(barmode = "stack")
```

[image: result]

A related GitHub issue can be found [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/2213).